# JOOMLA, Best way to make alternate layouts for articles?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I can't find a answer for this, I want to know what is the best way to have an alternative layouts for articles in Joomla.

Comment: can you define an example of "alternative layout" please. Also, what version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for a way to create additional Alternative Layouts for articles. Under parameter tab *"Article Options"*:
[image: Joomla article alternative layout]

If that is the case, its very close to the other provided answers here. Its just that you got to rename the copied default.php file to something else. If you rename it to custom.php it will end up with the text "custom" like the image above.

Here goes my shot for a step by step:

1. Find the default layout file(s). You could use the ones provided by the *com_content* component. They can be found at **components/com_content/views/article/tmpl**. Copy both *default.php* and *default_links.php*.
2. Now you need to rename and copy the file(s) into a template. The target template can be any of the installed templates. Using beez_20 the new path for the copied file(s) should be **templates/beez_20/html/com_content/article/*custom*.php** and **templates/beez_20/html/com_content/article/*custom*_links.php**.
3. Goto to edit article using the backend. Expand the *Article Options* tab and find *Alternative Layout*. Select your new layout.

Your template might already provide a article override. If so, you might want to use the files of that template instead (instead of the ones in step 1). So if you are using beez_20, you could copy **templates/beez_20/html/com_content/article/default.php** and **templates/beez_20/html/com_content/article/default_links.php**.

Helpful links:

- [Using Joomla’s Template and Layout Override](http://writenowdesign.com/joomla-tutorials/joomla-core-features/using-joomlas-template-and-layout-override/)
- [Layout overrides in Joomla 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_1.6)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would either to install another content component - such as [k2](http://getk2.org/) which is highly customizable. Or any other content component on [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction).

Alternatively you could create a template override on the existing [Joomla Template](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core). This is preferable to editing the files directly in com_content component as the template overrides will never be overwritten whereas the core files will be in any Joomla Updates. I should add, hopefully unnecessarily that this requires Joomla 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 2.5 or 3.0 (although this is still in beta as of present). So make sure you're not using 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

To create an alternative layout for the built in articles component the best way to do it is probably to create a template over-ride.

See this article on [docs.joomla.org](http://docs.joomla.org/) on "[How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)"

Answer (score 0):

Creating an alternative for an article layout is pretty straight forward. You can achieve this by using the core layout override with your published template(s).

First you want to get/copy the core article layout file:

**components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php**

Then place it into your published template:

**templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/com_content/article/default.php**

If the template you are using doesn't have the **html** folder, then you will have to create that folder and each folder to make that path correct.

Once you have this in place, all you need to do is make changes to that **default.php** file you have just place in the template and that is it!