# Joomla DB Customizing

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm new to Joomla (3). I've researched a bit but could not find an exact match for what I need to know.

I need to create other categories (not referring to Joomla "categories") in the mysql DB so I can assign them to each article (not Tags). These would control how each article is formatted in the layout.

So let's say Article->Type1 = .classType1 in the layout and Article->Type2 = .classType2 in the layout.

So my basic question is: how would you go about adding data to the Joomla db outside of the basic table that's created - is it a simple process, can it be done withing the framework or do I have to code extra stuff??

I hope I'm clear in my question...

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend making changes like that to the database. You might be best off creating a Plugin

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to "control the article layout" on an individual basis. You don't need to do anything specific for this as Joomla supports this already. Here is a parallel StackOverflow question: [JOOMLA, Best way to make alternate layouts for articles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520801/joomla-best-way-to-make-alternate-layouts-for-articles)

It also has additional links to get you started.

A quick and "dirty" way would be to simply wrap all the text in the article content in a div with a specific class and then you can override the default layout/styles accordingly.

My personal opinion is try and learn how to create alternate layouts - which is really what you want and once you know how to do it will also be fun to work with.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It wasn't really what I needed but that's because of me. I think I overestimated Joomla's capabilities to bend to what I need. I have done research on the issue and implementing such things would require a huge effort that erases any advantage Joomla might have as an already built CMS.